# Detectar comunicación con dispositivo conectado a puerto serial C#

Tags: c#, serialport

Tengo entendido que no se puede obtener información de un dispositivo conectado al puerto serial (Name, DeviceID, etc.). Y quiero saber si hay una forma que no sepa de hacer esto o de saber si un dispositivo ha sido conectado a este puerto y sea haciendo un tipo de ping hacia el periférico.

De antemano, gracias.

Comment: Hasta donde sé, en comunicación serial tradicional no hay un estándar, diferente es en USB, que también es serial (con esteroides). Un saludo.

Comment: Si se podra detectar los puertos COM que se estan usando, la pc brindara al menos esa informacion, no se si el nombre o deviceid, pero la presencia si se puede detectar.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando la clase **SerialPort**, puedes invocar al método **GetPortNames**.
Ejemplo:

```
string[] puertosDisponibles = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
```

Si el dispositivo conectado al puerto aparece en esa lista, significa que esta conectado.